# Archived messages are not render properly on chat box Library JSXC.js (MAM-0313)

Tags: xmpp, chat, archiving

Expected behavior

Chat archiving functionality coming from backend properly,And render On the chatBox

Actual behavior
Steps to reproduce the behavior

```
Clicking on the Load more messages
2.In network i can see all the message coming from backend is ok and I can can see the xml having all the messages,But when its going to render on the chatbox its misses some messages its happen the same when I am tried again to load.
3.Conclusion is that some message are not rendering in the chat box.
```

Environment

```
JSXC version: v3.2.1 - 2017-06-01
Host system and version:
Browser vendor and version: Chrome(Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit))/Firefox
Any browser plugins enabled: NO
XMPP server vendor and version: Openfire 4.1.4 (XMPP)
Is your XMPP server working with other clients as expected?: On android/IOS its working fine they are using some other libraries for chat.
```

Logs
Javascript

No Errors found in Console

Thanks and regard:

Manish Jain

Comment: Any pro developer Here???